# find all occurrences between tag

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to find all `<br>` instances in the following string, but only in the "categories" class:

```
<td>bla<br>bla</td><td class="categories">cat1<br>cat2<br>cat3</td>
```

I am realy new to regex, and this is what I tried so far, but it only finds the first `<br>` after cat1 and takes the whole part in front of it in the result as well...

```
(?>categories">).*?<br>
```

EDIT: I want to find all `<br>` occurences to replace them with a comma. For the moment I'm using a text editor (Sublime Text) to achieve this...

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: what language are you talking about?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: using or talking about... ;)

Comment: Whoops! Using.. :P @WouterHuysentruit

Comment: Are you trying to do this within the browser, or server-side? When you find the `<br>` instances, what do you want to do with them? Count them, insert text after them...?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use regex? What are you trying to validate?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

If you want to find html elements using class variables then you want to look into javascript or jquery

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags